# Is there a Perl module that collapses file system paths such as a/b/.. or a//b?

Tags: perl, filesystems

I'm writing a program where I have to remove redundancy in paths, e.g.

```
a/b/.. -> a
a//b   -> a/b
a/./b  -> a/b
```

Does any existing module do this?

Update: This normalization/canonicalization is described by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-38). I only need the path segment normalization part.

Of course, this is simple to implement. I'm still wondering if it's already been packaged into some module.

Comment: In general URLs don't adhere to the same principals as file system URLs. For example, there are many web services out there that use path-like syntax for passing parameters. Example: In the URL `http://.../path/to/script/controller/action` the actual script executed might be `script` which uses `controller/action` in order to determine what it should do.

Comment: @MoritzBunkus That's right. My program is for determining whether file system URLs are unique (disregarding links). I'm not sure if "URL" is the right word here.

Comment: note that `a/b/..` is not necessarily `a`, depending on soft links `..` could take you somewhere else than `a`

Comment: @mirod: Yes. I'm disregarding symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Form path and meaning or relations of elements in hierarchy of URL is not specified in standard. Depending on server there could be no hierarchy at all - elements split by `/` could be treated as positional or order could have no meaning at all. Because of that, there's no specific module to handle that task for URLs.

However, if you're absolutely sure about how target server works, you can simply adapt [`File::Spec`](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aSpec) to your needs: extract path from URL (for example with [`URI`](http://p3rl.org/URI)), process it as it would be a file path, and then put it back.

Considering your comment that you'll be working with regular file names on file system, you don't even need to extract anything from path - `File::Spec` is enough for all your needs.

If you wish to work around `File::Spec` (by design) not resolving `..`, use `splitpath` from it to extract directory part of name, `splitdir` to split it to directories and then just iterate of that array, `splice`'ing two elements each time you encounter `..`. Use `catdir` and `catfile` to pack results back.

Comment: File::Spec::canonpath() seems to do it, except it doesn't collapse `..`s (due to possible symlinks). I can't use their suggested Cwd::realpath(), as the path might not exist.

Comment: @Andreas, you can easily implement `..` collapsing with functions in module, see update.